# Changing behaviour using a closure in c++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, closures

I have a base class and a closure, the base class always gets extended by a specific class, but its not determined what the base class specificly contains.

Now i want to override the behavior of the base class while changing the behaviour of the specific class.

Here is a simple example of what i am trying to achieve:

```
class base
{
    public:
        inline void print()
        {
            std::cout << "test!" << std::endl;
        }
};

template <class T>
class closure
{
    public:
        inline closure()
        {
            if (!std::is_convertible<T*, base*>::value) {
                throw "error!";
            }

            this->baseInstance = new T();
        }

        /*
         * In this class the behavior of test should be extended/overridden.
         * in this case base::print
        */

        ~closure()
        {
            delete this->baseInstance;
        }

        inline T * operator-> ()
        {
            return this->baseInstance;
        }
    private:
        T * baseInstance;
};

class test : public base
{
    public:
        inline void otherStuff()
        {
            /* ... **/
        }
        /* .. */
};
```

In this case i want to override `base::print()`, but maintain the full functionality of `test::otherStuff()` when it gets called through the closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution on my own.

In the end it was pretty easy,
since i knew what functions i want to change,
i wrote the whole function of the base class as a `std::function<void()>` and then i friended the closure so that it was able to override it.

The method call of `base::print()` got changed into the call of the `std::function<void()>` and now it works quite well.